# How to open a office document directly from a gmail without downloading it first?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, attachments

I have two windows computers (using Google Chrome)

When I click the attached file, 
One PC downloads it first (I do not want this)
Another PC opens it directly in office, (I want this)

But I do not know how where to go, can not find any option to enable direct opening of documents without downloading them first.

[image]

Comment: Attachments to drafted emails on Gmail will download and open, whereas, the mails with attachments you receive can open the attachments in the web browser. This is what I have experienced so far

Answer (score 1):

When you download the file type you want to opened automatically there will be a dropdown arrow next to the file name in the bottom notification bar.

Click that arrow and a menu with an option to "Always open files of this type" can be checked.

In the future all files of that type will be opened automatically.